# Integrating $\exp(-(\frac xa)^b-(\frac xc)^d)$

Tags: exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

For $a,b,c,d,x>0$, does
$$
\int \exp\left(-\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^b-\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)^d\right)\,\mathrm dx
$$
have a closed form using erf, gammas, etc? Wolfram Alpha (standard) was not of help, so I am wondering if I am missing a standard transformation.

Comment: MathJax works in the title, don't you know?

Comment: I am not completely sure of this, but, regarding indefinite integration, Wolfram Alpha uses [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). Therefore, if it says that there isn't closed-form antiderivative, there isn't.

Comment: shaun, I didn't know that. @rafa11111 said it had reached it's computational limit for the "standard" version.

Comment: @IanFellows I don't have any kind of account in Wolfram Alpha and it [returned](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+exp(-(x%2Fa)%5Eb-(x%2Fc)%5Ed)) "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions" just now for me

Answer (score 3):

$\int e^{-\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^b-\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)^d}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\left(\dfrac{x^b}{a^b}+\dfrac{x^d}{c^d}\right)^n}{n!}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^nC_k^n\dfrac{x^{bk}}{a^{bk}}\dfrac{x^{dn-dk}}{c^{dn-dk}}}{n!}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{dn+(b-d)k}}{k!(n-k)!a^{bk}c^{dn-dk}}~dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{dn+(b-d)k+1}}{k!(n-k)!a^{bk}c^{dn-dk}(dn+(b-d)k+1)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{dn+(b-d)k+1}}{k!(n-k)!a^{bk}c^{dn-dk}(dn+(b-d)k+1)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k}x^{dn+bk+1}}{k!n!a^{bk}c^{dn}(dn+bk+1)}+C$

Which relates to [Srivastava-Daoust Function](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/36/16.pdf)

Comment: Fantastic! It could use a bit more information on where the summations come from. Unfortunately for me, the infinite sum is a bit of a stumbling block in terms of using this formulation.